# Hide table column only if lack place

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with 2 columns. I want to show them both full, the second with right align. Now I make that with `width: 100%;` for the first column. But now the second column is always wrapped by words.

I want the second column to be on the right, but wrapped only if there is not enough space to show both columns full.

Comment: http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/12/0604/h_1338812863_8983329_5caff86199.jpeg - I want the date to be shown in one line but still on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS styling to the cell on the right:

```
td {white-space: nowrap;}
```

This will prevent the text inside the cell from wrapping, as in your example.

Comment: But I want it to wrap when there is not much space, for example on a mobile phone. To make enough place for the first column.

Comment: Well, if you have two columns and you always want to "prefer" the left column, remove width from the left-side cell and give the right-side cell {width: 1%; white-space: nowrap;}. This will make it as small as possible, but never wrap the text..... or otherwise I'm misunderstanding your comment/question.

Comment: In your advice the right column will never wrap. And I want to 'prefer' the left column but show the right one in one lint **only when there's much space for it**.

Comment: HTML/CSS doesn't really behave conditionally in this way. Unless you want to mix PHP (or whatever) into it, your easiest option is probably to experiment with 1% / 2% / 3% / etc for the right-side column width, and removing "white-space: nowrap", until you find that it behaves like you want it to. Do remember that the layout will change depending on your users' screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really thinking about mobile or smaller screens on this case you should consider using a media query. In this case, when the screen falls below a certain width, you can specify a wider width for the right column.

http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/